# Populating Index view with view model. EF 6, MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, viewmodel

I'm really struggling with this and I hope someone can help (I've received lots of help on another topic) I'm working with Entity Framework 6.1.3 and MVC5. In my ProductsController the Index method looks like so:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

// GET: /Products/
public  ActionResult Index()
{
    var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.ProductImage);

    IEnumerable<DisplayProductsViewModel> model = products.Select(p => new DisplayProductsViewModel() 
    { 
        Id = p.ProductId,
        Name = p.ProductName, 
        Image = p.ProductImage, 
        Price = p.ProductPrice.ToString() }).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

My **DisplayProductsViewModel** view model looks like so:

```
namespace AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels
{
    public class DisplayProductsViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public ProductImage Image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my Index view looks like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels.DisplayProductsViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">

        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

When I view in browser I get an empty page, nothing shows. I get no errors though so that's a step in the right direction. This is my first time working with view models, and when I debug **model** always comes back as an empty list.

I know an extra set of eyes is sometimes what it takes, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here's the **Product** EF model

```
namespace AccessorizeForLess.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int ProductImageId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ProductPrice { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

        public virtual ProductImage ProductImage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm going to pull out the view model and see if the page populates

Comment: Are you sure that `var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.ProductImage);` is being populated correctly? and can you include your data model for `Product`

Comment: I went back to the EF Model and nothing displays, so now I get to figure out why. In Visual Studio 2015 it works correctly, and this is the same code

Comment: Thanks, I got to the bottom of it and now it works. I truly appreciate your help